# data processing using r

Tags: r

I have a file .ped who contains several columns, and I want to extract informations from it. 
Here a sample of my data (there is no header):

```
1  1  1 
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  4  1
3  5  2
...
```

The first column indicates the ID family, the second the ID individual, the third the sex of the individual.

I read the table as a dataframe

```
ped <- read.table("pedigree.ped", header=FALSE)
```

How I can compute the number of families exist (one family can appear more than one time and I want to consider them as one)?
I have a sex column where 1 designate male and 2 female, how I can get the distribution of males and females in the data set?

I'm newbie to R, if you can give some code!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: post a sample of your data, please.

Comment: ^^^this - `head(ped)`

Comment: please give me indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to R, I would suggest looking into excel first. The operations you are asking for is fairly simple and can be done in excel.

If you want to use R then look into data.frame indexing, subsetting etc.

If you are familiar with SQL, look in to [sqldf package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html)

Number of families:

```
numFamilies <- length(unique(ped[,1]))
```

Number of males & females:

```
numMales <- sum(ped[,3] == 1)
numFemales <- sum(ped[,3] == 2)
```

Comment: what is the relation between SQL and R?!!

Comment: Many folks new to R syntax are familiar with sql interface. select, count, groupby etc. You can query a data.frame object using sqldf package.

Comment: @e4e5f4 : not necessarily.

Comment: OP: Updated my answer.
user1493368: Yeah, I should have highlighted the "if you are familiar with sql" part :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this for exploring the data:

```
For family:
table(ped[,1])

For sex: 
table(ped[,3])
```